# Proper obfusction and minification of Ionic 3/Angular2 app that has lazy-loaded pages and components

Tags: angular, obfuscation, minify, ionic3

I have just finished building an Ionic 3 **Web app** and I opted for lazy-loading due to the size of the the app itself. I have however run into efficiency problems when it comes to initial app load. The `main.js` that get built is (4.3MB) which can take quite a while if the network is slow ( I realize this would be a breeze on an actual device). I have resulted to showing a "loading" .gif while I wait for it to load and I realize this is not actually solving the problem but actually adding to it.

I looked into the `main.js` and the file would definitely be a lot smaller if it were minified and  obfuscated.

I do not have experience with either and the tutorials I find on the net do not cover lazy loaded modules...Most just broke my app.

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction? Or at least tell me if this is doable?